# undefined reference to "boost::archive..." g++ / wsl

Tags: c++, boost, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using draco and boost together. Draco is working well after this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313136/how-to-include-the-draco-dec-library).

I have tried to install boost and i think its done. 
[image: boost]

Now i try to run this command in vs-code on wsl :

```
 g++ -I ~/local/include -L ~/local/lib -o prog ObjContainer.cpp -ldracodec -lboost_system
```

errors:

```
ObjContainer.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_iarchiveINS0_15binary_iarchiveEED2Ev[_ZN5boost7archive6detail15common_iarchiveINS0_15binary_iarchiveEED5Ev]+0x22): undefined reference to `boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::~basic_iarchive()'
/tmp/ccqY0aGT.o: In function `boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::~binary_iarchive_impl()':
ObjContainer.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive20binary_iarchive_implINS0_15binary_iarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEED2Ev[_ZN5boost7archive20binary_iarchive_implINS0_15binary_iarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEED5Ev]+0x32): undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_binary_iprimitive()'
/tmp/ccqY0aGT.o: In function `boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::binary_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&, unsigned int)':
ObjContainer.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive20binary_oarchive_implINS0_15binary_oarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEEC2ERSoj[_ZN5boost7archive20binary_oarchive_implINS0_15binary_oarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEEC5ERSoj]+0x55): undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_binary_oprimitive(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, bool)'
ObjContainer.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive20binary_oarchive_implINS0_15binary_oarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEEC2ERSoj[_ZN5boost7archive20binary_oarchive_implINS0_15binary_oarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEEC5ERSoj]+0xab): undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_binary_oprimitive()'
/tmp/ccqY0aGT.o: In function `boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::binary_iarchive_impl(std::istream&, unsigned int)':
ObjContainer.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive20binary_iarchive_implINS0_15binary_iarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEEC2ERSij[_ZN5boost7archive20binary_iarchive_implINS0_15binary_iarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEEC5ERSij]+0x55): undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_binary_iprimitive(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, bool)'
ObjContainer.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive20binary_iarchive_implINS0_15binary_iarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEEC2ERSij[_ZN5boost7archive20binary_iarchive_implINS0_15binary_iarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEEC5ERSij]+0xab): undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_binary_iprimitive()'
/tmp/ccqY0aGT.o: In function `boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::init(unsigned int)':
ObjContainer.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive20binary_oarchive_implINS0_15binary_oarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEE4initEj[_ZN5boost7archive20binary_oarchive_implINS0_15binary_oarchiveEcSt11char_traitsIcEE4initEj]+0x21): undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_binary_oarchive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>::init()'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `boost::archive` class is part of Boost.Serialization library.

You need to link with `-lboost_serialization -lboost_system` at the end.